# I am trying to use the grep function in a script but it is not working, Although it is working in the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, grep

I want to count the number of the G8LE word in my file so I opened a terminal and I used:

```
grep -o -i G8LE C60_TAPC_GRM_box.gro | wc -l
```

and it worked.

I tried to write a script composed of many steps and this was my first step. so I created a .sh file and I wrote the same command but with

```
va1=$(grep -o -i G8LE C60_TAPC_GRM_box.gro | wc -l)
```

and then I tried to run the file by using bash trial5.sh, nothing happened and it didn't work. please tell me what is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: Nothing happened, it didn't print out the number, however, I followed Raffa instructions to add  echo "$va1" and it worked now :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `va1` needs to be put into action.

The variable `va1`, *although it contains the output of a command ( **this is called command substitution** )*, is not actually recognized by the shell as a command by itself and is not going to be executed like one. It needs to be called by a command in your script.

Try adding `echo "$va1"` in the second line of your script like so:

```
va1=$(grep -o -i G8LE C60_TAPC_GRM_box.gro | wc -l)


echo "$va1"
```

You might as well need to add the full path of the `C60_TAPC_GRM_box.gro` file like so:

```
va1=$(grep -o -i G8LE /home/YourUserName/C60_TAPC_GRM_box.gro | wc -l)
```

Best of luck

Comment: `val` doesn't contain a command. It contains the output of a command. The command was executed and its output stored in the variable when the script was run.